# How to use underscore.string globally in a web page (with requireJS)

Tags: requirejs, underscore.js, underscore.string.js

The documentation says once underscore.string included in my application, the library is available using **s**, **__s** global variables (http://epeli.github.io/underscore.string/#others), or within underscore properties **__.str** or **__.string**.

This simple code should then work properly (with config paths correctly set) :

```
require(['underscore','underscore.string'], function(){
     console.log(s('test').capitalize().value());
});
```

But it does not work at all. Here is a simple jsfiddle example. I probably did something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

https://jsfiddle.net/mvenrtgy/10/

The relevant test code is:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'underscore':'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min',
    'underscore.string':'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.string/3.3.4/underscore.string.min'
  }
});
require(['underscore','underscore.string'], function(){

  var t = 'This is a simple text I would like to SLUGIFY using unsercore.string';

  // underscore is there!
  console.log(typeof _)

  // now check where underscore.string is...
  console.log(typeof _.str);
  console.log(typeof _.string);
  console.log(typeof s);
  console.log(typeof _s);

  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = '<p>Sample text : ' + t + '</p>';
  // this line will cause an error
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += '<p><em>Slugified</em> text : ' + s(t).slugify().value() + '</p>';


});
```

Answer (score 0):

`underscore.string` is a well-behaved AMD library so it does not pollute the global space. You should change your `require` call so that it gets the parameters that correspond to the modules you are loading:

```
require(['underscore','underscore.string'], function(_, s){
```

By just making this change to your code, I get something that works. The 2nd line of your test comes up as:

> *Slugified text* : this-is-a-simple-text-i-would-like-to-slugify-using-unsercore-string

Also, while `underscore.string` *started* as an `underscore` extension, it has grown beyond that, so you cannot access it through the `_` global that `underscore` leaks into the global space, *unless* you take care of mixing it in with `underscore`. The [documentation](https://epeli.github.io/underscore.string/#underscore-js-lo-dash-integration) says you can do this:

```
_.mixin(s.exports());
```

But the documentation recommends against it because `underscore.string` will interfere with some of the basic functions that `underscore` exports. Use at your own risks.

Comment: For sure I know we can mix it within underscore but I really don't want to get into trouble later with some interference with underscore. I also can't use it like you suggested, in require call, because I actually need to use backbone.string function within underscore/backbone template system. I forgot to mention sorry. Therefore, underscore templates engine works only with global variables / functions. I have no choice but find a way to make underscore.string accessible globally....